# Error: Missing operand after 'ItemRecord' operator

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, datagridview

I want to show filtered values in dataGridView for specific date. I have tried many options but none of them worked. I want to show record in datagridview for specific date. Please suggest me some solution.

```
    string plus = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1).ToString();
    string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemRecord", con);
    var dataset = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
    this.itemRecordBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("SELECT * FROM ItemRecord WHERE cast(date as date) between '" + date +"' and '"+ plus +"'");
```

Answer (score 0):

> [*To form a filter value, specify the name of a column followed by an operator and a value to filter on.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx)

So `.Filter = "columnname = 'something'";` is valid, the `SELECT` is not.

`CAST()` is also not valid as a filter does not re-query the database with SQL, for expressions you can use  [see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx). (You would use `CONVERT()`)

To use what you have consider adding the `WHERE` clause to the initial query instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this applying your condition while selecting from DB, or you should change your code like this

```
this.itemRecordBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("date >= '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' AND date < '{1:yyyy-MM-dd}'", date, plus);
```

Comment: I have tried this, but its not showing any record, its showing empty dataGridView table

Comment: Can you share results without filter? I think its because time part of data

Comment: Its working now, but after converting the datetime to YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: I did this and now its working `string plus = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: thanks man :) 
would you like to share some of your account so i could contact you for any query?